# can we create number of fields at a time with same data type in mysql?

Tags: mysql

alter table students 
 add s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,s7 int;

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's2,s3,s4,s5,s6,s7 int' at line 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add several columns at once but you need to declare the types per column:

```
alter table t add column (s5 int, s6 int);
```

You can also use:

```
alter table t add (s5 int, s6 int);
```

but I prefer the first one. Note that the parentheses are mandantory.

You don't mention your version, but the syntax have been valid since at least 5.1:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html

Comment: You can also use `alter table t add column s5 int, add column s6 int;` (no parentheses!). The `column` is not needed here either.

Comment: Learn something new every day!  (I see it in the 5.0 syntax, too.)